# What are "those oscillating tools"?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

[This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189/are-those-oscillating-tools-any-good) asks about oscillating tools, using off-site links to describe what they are. Since those links are long-since broken, there's no real indication of kind of tool they're talking about other than that it oscillates.

There's a link to a blog post in a comment, but that blog site appears to be down at the moment.

Can the question be improved to include a photo? And maybe an English description of the tool?

Comment: If you can find better links, please do replace them. That's exactly what the edit ability was built for - keeping old posts up-to-date so they can stay useful.

Comment: Fixed Harbor Freight link, the Fein link was still working

Comment: @HerrBag: The Fein link takes me to a domain squatter that shows a bunch of random links with Fein in the name. I hesitate to click on them to find out what happens.